# Custom Font with JavaFX SceneBuilder

Tags: java, css, javafx, fonts, scenebuilder

JavaFX's SceneBuilder is very useful, but I want to add a custom font to it. In the past, this has worked, though I have no idea how. Screenshot:

[image]

Minecraftia is not in SceneBuilder as a default font, but it worked when I defined the Minecraftia font in CSS. I tried doing the same with the new font i want (Roboto), but it doesn't show up in SceneBuilder. I know that i could style the labels in CSS, but I liked it better when the font popped up in SceneBuilder. Does anyone know why/how custom fonts show up in SceneBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

**updated**

Since Java 8 JavaFX supports the **@font-face** rule that can be used to add fonts. As a first step the font file must be added to the application.

Once this is done the font can be defined in CSS by using the **@font-face** rule: in your case

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('Roboto-Medium.ttf');
}

.text {
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto";
}
```

check [this blog](http://www.guigarage.com/2014/10/integrate-custom-fonts-javafx-application-using-css/) and [a answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855677/how-to-embed-ttf-fonts-is-javafx-2-2/16866962#16866962) for more information.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: If this is not useful than i have mentioned one link down. @Nitram rather doing this you can answer question , if you know. Otherwise let others to try atleast.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question. But the question is to get the SceneBuilder to show a specific font in the selection. This answer provides a way to set a font in the code. That is something entirely different compared to the question. In addition the one asking the question also said that he is a aware that it is possible to set a custom font in the css. Making this answer even less useful.

Comment: This above code is similar is to show how to set font and all , if we want to use it in schenebuilder. you can set fonts and its properties in schenebuilder as shown in screenshot of question.

Answer (score -1):

Install the font to your system

In windows 7 you can just double click the true type font file and it will ask if you want to install it...