# How to display special characters in Java FX Application

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, javafx, fxml

I have an application in **Java FX**, I have the views in **FXML** files. The thing is that I have some labels with special characters as: " á,é,í,ó,ú,¿" and none of them are displayed well  when I executed the application on a linux enviroment, but in Windows 8 all is fine.
Following, I'll show some examples:

[image: This is an example of alerts with special character]

[image]

So, I'm working in eclipse I checked the the *default encoding configuration* of the project for FXML files, and I have this:

[image]

So, how could I handle this?Thanks

Comment: Probably the font on your Linux system doesn't have these characters. You can try to include a font in your program and use it explicitly for your labels. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30245558/4185959)

Comment: @sillyfly I will check it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Those are special character in UTF-8 encoding.. 
So To represent them you need to use character entity ..
For example,
character **á**
should be typed in as **'&aacute'**

For other character refer this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references