# How to add awesome font in the Scene Builder

Tags: javafx

I wanted add font awesome in the Scene Builder, but I don't know what is wrong 
I have download from this site it doesn't work : 
https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx/downloads/

any help guys please,i would appreciate you
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430121/how-to-use-font-awesome-in-a-fxml-project-javafx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use font awesome in a fxml project (javafx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430121/how-to-use-font-awesome-in-a-fxml-project-javafx)

Answer (score -1):

See, always first try to google your issue, which the prospects and the issues you are facing out or what you want to do there,

As per my understanding, you are facing to add the custom fonts using scene builder in JavaFX right!

I would recommend below said given blog and issue thread on the similar,

1. [Adding a Custom JavaFX Component to Scene Builder 2.0 (Part 2)](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/adding-custom-javafx-component-to-scene-builder-2-0-part-2/)
2. [How to set custom fonts in JavaFX Scene Builder using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535564/how-to-set-custom-fonts-in-javafx-scene-builder-using-css)

hope these above links will help you, thanks.

Comment: i'm not talking about this my brother, just my problem is how to add font awesome and Glyph in the Scene builder

Comment: sometimes with the issue we stuck, and we required the exact one, if you are going to need add font one or two, why you are depending on some tools, just download the font, add to the resource dir, add by css part in JavaFX, that's simple, otherwise you have to check manually where are you failing to do that right!

Comment: Sorry my brother still you don't get what i mean, please  watch this video, you will understand what i'm talking about   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWuGagl16d8

Comment: he is talking about font awesome icons, not about regular fonts