# Custom font load time

Tags: java, javafx

In my application I am loading  additional fonts from code, before showing `Stage`. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16866962/6708868) solution and my fonts are in application jar and loaded before any component need them. Problem is when I create distribution jar. Either starting by `java -jar` or simply double click on jar, loading fonts takes about 10 seconds and then `Stage` shows. From user point it looks like app is not starting. Running application from IDE does not produce delay, app start immediately. My code is simple:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final Font fontRoboto = Font.loadFont(Main.class.getResource("/path/to/font/Roboto-Regular.ttf").toExternalForm(), 12);
    final Font fontAwesome = Font.loadFont(Main.class.getResource("/path/to/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf").toExternalForm(), 12);

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/path/to/my/view/View.fxml"));
    final Parent root = loader.load();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I created a simple workaround, it just first shows `ProgressIndicator`, loads fonts in background `Task` and on success replaces `root` in `Scene`:

```
ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(-1);
pi.setMaxSize(200, 200);
StackPane sp = new StackPane(pi);
Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 1200, 800);

Task fontTask = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        final Font fontRoboto = Font.loadFont(Main.class.getResource("/path/to/font/Roboto-Regular.ttf").toExternalForm(), 12);
        final Font fontAwesome = Font.loadFont(Main.class.getResource("/path/to/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf").toExternalForm(), 12);
        return null;
    }
};

fontTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    scene.setRoot(root);
});
new Thread(fontTask, "FONT TASK").start();

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

But this is only a workaround and showing `ProgressIndicator` always on start of application, just for loading fonts is unefficient.

Creating separate `Task` for loading fonts gives me another question. Do I have to call `Font.loadFont` in JavaFX Application Thread? From my code snippet I assume that fonts does not have to be loaded in FX thread. All fonts shows in application correctly.

My OS: Windows 7 Home Premium SP1

Java: Java 1.8.0_101-b13

IDE: NetBeans 8.1

Has anybody encountered this issue?

Comment: Try profiling: google "visualvm profiler tutorial".