# JavaFX 9 @font-face css not apply at run time

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

I have applied a custom font named of file "digital-7.ttf", the name inside digital-7. the approches works correctly in scenebuilder, but when I start the application the custom font does not work at all.
the font file located at resource's folder /font/digital-7.ttf.
I don't know what exactly causes the problem since the css file is applied correctly.

Here the css file:

```
@font-face {
    src: url('/font/digital-7.ttf');
}

.text {    
    -fx-font-size: 30px;    
}

#lblTotal {    
    -fx-font-family: 'Digital-7';
    -fx-font-size: 60px;
    -fx-text-fill: greenyellow;    
}

#testId {
    -fx-font-family: 'Digital-7';
    -fx-text-fill: red;
    -fx-font-size: 60px;
}

#lblDate,#lblTitle {
    -fx-font-family: 'Digital-7';
    -fx-font-size: 60px;
}

#blackscreen {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-padding: 5px;    
}

#comptoirRoot {
    -fx-background-color: #ffffff;
}

.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled:focused {
    -fx-background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

Comment: Is your code modular?

Comment: No, it just compiles

Comment: So you don't have a `module-info` in your code and you don't use the modulepath?

Comment: yes i don't create module-info file !

Comment: Sorry for asking twice; your response left me unsure if you understood my question. Unfortunately, I only had an idea of what the issue could be if you were using modules. Without modules, I have no idea.

Comment: okay, let's try it, even though i'm not using modules capability.

Comment: hmm ... don't know if some kind of automatic default font-name building from the source is expected to work, but even if so, it might get confused by the difference of lower/uppercase first letter. You might try to explicitly add  a font-name to the font-face rule as done in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855677/how-to-embed-ttf-fonts-is-javafx-2-2 (and other examples) It's a long shot, not personal experience in this area ;)