# How to Embed Font in JavaFX?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, javafx, graphics

How can I embed a custom font in a JavaFX Application? I've tried making a fonts.mf file, and following the instructions to a similar question linked below. I don't want to use CSS if I don't have to. I want to focus on learning core JavaFX stuff.

Here is what I've been messing around with:

```
private static Label makeTitle() {
   Label title = new Label("Bandit King");
   Font font = new Font("OldStyle", 40);
   title.setFont(font);

   return title;
}
```

my fonts.mf file contains just this line:

```
OldStyle = /home/myName/Desktop/My_Java_Projects/Bandit_King/banditKing/OLDSH.TTF
```

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855677/how-to-embed-ttf-fonts-is-javafx-2-2). Eclipse says, "CustomFontApp, cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: You don't show your attempt to load the font (i.e. `Font.loadFont`). And what is `CustomFontApp`?

Comment: I have no idea what CustomFontApp is, it is just  written in the question I linked. I thought `Font font = new Font("OldStyle", 40);` did load the font.

Comment: As far as I know, the constructors and factory methods simply search the existing fonts for a best match. You have to actually load any custom fonts with `Font.loadFont` or `@font-face` before use. Also, it looks like `CustomFontApp` is the name of the example `Application` class in the linked non-duplicate; you can't use that in your own code unless you also create that class.

Comment: :/ sorry, I should've noticed that. I have another problem. I can't seem to use `toExternalForm()` in the same way. Eclipse says, "The method `toExternalForm()` is undefined for the type InputStream"

Comment: Post the code that is causing the errors.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried making a fonts.mf file

You don't need it.

> This is not a duplicate of this question. Eclipse says, "CustomFontApp, cannot be resolved to a type".

`CustomFontApp` is just the name of a class used in the answer you linked - your class name is obviously different, and you should've changed it.

This line:

```
Font font = new Font("OldStyle", 40);
```

will load `OldStyle` font only if it's installed on your system. You aren't using an installed font, but the embedded one, so that won't work.

You need to use [Font.loadFont(InputStream, double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html#loadFont-java.io.InputStream-double-) or [Font.loadFont(String, double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html#loadFont-java.lang.String-double-) to load your custom font from disk:

```
// use this to load font from your application's resource folder (`res/fonts/OLDSIH.TTF`)
Font font = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/OLDSIH.TTF"), 40);

// or this one to load font from the specified (absolute) path
// (not recommended, use the method above or, at least, change this into relative path):
Font font = Font.loadFont("file:///home/myName/Desktop/My_Java_Projects/Bandit_King/banditKing/OLDSH.TTF", 40);
```

Comment: I did what you said, but Eclipse is throwing an error with `getClass()` It says, "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method `getClass()` from the type Object". My code is `Font font = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/OLDSH.TTF"), 40);`

Comment: That's because `makeTitle` method is `static`, while `getClass()` is an instance method, so it can't be called without an object. You really should move your code from `main` to `start` method, but if you just want a quickfix for a problem above - change `getClass()` into `Main.class`, where `Main` is the name of your main class.