# In JavaFX I imported a custom font using Java but it doesn't work with CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I was following the instructions given in the correct answer in this post.

[Javafx How to display custom font in webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325979/javafx-how-to-display-custom-font-in-webview)

The font file is located at the same package as the Main class.
[image]

This is my full code.

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Font.loadFont(Main.class.getResource("TRON.TTF").toExternalForm(),10);

       StackPane pane = new StackPane();
       Label label = new Label("Text");

       pane.getChildren().add(label);
       label.setStyle("-fx-font-family:'TRON'; -fx-font-size: 50px;-fx-text-fill: red");

       Scene scene = new Scene(pane,300,300);
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

The font color and the font size has been affected. But the Tron font family has not been used.

I downloaded the font ttf file from [here](https://www.dafont.com/tron.font).

Comment: Your code worked for me.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(Main.class.getResource("TRON.TTF"));` display?

Comment: @VGR It displays this file:/C:/Users/prave_000/OneDrive/Programs/Java/OOP%20-%20Y2/04%20Practice/JavaFx%20Tutorials/out/production/JavaFx%20Tutorials/sample/TRON.TTF

Comment: OneDrive could be your problem. Just a guess. Try moving the project to the `NetBeans`(assuming here) project folder or a local folder under `MyDocuments`.